# How do I start a shell without terminal emulation in Python Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, terminal, paramiko, ansi-escape

Is there a way to start a shell without terminal emulation in Python Paramiko?

- I have tried using `exec_command` but I really need an interactive shell.
- Using `invoke_shell()` I get a terminal and can issue commands, but from Windows 10 OpenSSH server I get an output with ANSI escape sequences, including `H` code, which is not easy to process to plain text. Refer to [Decoding data from WIN10 ssh server (response of paramiko recv())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633222/decoding-data-from-win10-ssh-server-response-of-paramiko-recv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paramiko [`SSHClient.invoke_shell`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.invoke_shell) opens "shell" SSH channel. What is basically only a shorthand for executing user's default shell. Otherwise it does not differ to what SSH "exec" channel (used by [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command)) does.

Both "shell" and "exec" SSH channels can be started with or without the terminal emulation. It's only that Paramiko `SSHClient.invoke_shell` method does not offer that option (while `SSHClient.exec_command` does – via its `get_pty` parameter).

There are two alternatives:

- Use `SSHClient.exec_channel` to start the shell explicitly, like

  ```
    ssh.exec_command("/bin/bash")
  ```

  On Linux servers, you may even be able to avoid hard-coding the shell path by using the `SHELL` environment variable:

  ```
    ssh.exec_command("$SHELL")
  ```

  Similar might be done on Windows using `%CMDSPEC%` (untested).
- Or re-implement `SSHClient.invoke_shell` to support execution without the terminal emulation.

  If you look at `SSHClient.invoke_shell` implementation, it does:

  ```
    chan = self._transport.open_session()
    chan.get_pty(term, width, height, width_pixels, height_pixels)
    chan.invoke_shell()
  ```

  All you need, is to do the same, just remove the [`Channel.get_pty`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.get_pty) call:

  ```
    chan = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
    chan.invoke_shell()
  ```

---

*Though note that there's a reason, why `SSHClient.invoke_shell` always uses the terminal emulation. The only purpose of SSH "shell" channel is implementing an interactive SSH terminal client (like PuTTY). A terminal client without the terminal emulation makes no sense.*

*That you want to use "shell" channel without the terminal emulation indicates, that you are* abusing *it for purposes for which it was not designed. Think twice, if there's not a better solution to what you are trying to do!*