# how to open a true terminal window using paramiko?

Tags: paramiko

Is it possible to open a terminal using `paramiko` like if we were executing `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` ? By terminal, I mean an actual terminal window and not a pseudo-terminal as it is done using `invoke_shell` method. I tried the recipe given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715388/how-do-i-start-a-shell-without-terminal-emulation-in-python-paramiko) but it does not work.